# How does the cardinality of a set and its powerset compare in the hereditarily rank-concordant constructible world?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, constructibility

Working in the constructible universe "$L$", if we define two kinds of ranks for any constructible set $x$, one being the ordinal index of the first $L_\alpha$ where $x$ appears as a **subset** of, and the other is the ordinal index of the first $L_\alpha$ where $x$ appears as an **element** of. Denote these as $\rho^\subseteq, \rho^\in$ respectively. A set $x$ to be called *rank-concordant* if and only if $\rho^\in(x)=\rho^\subseteq(x) +1$

Now, lets take the class $\sf HRC$ of all hereditarily rank-concordant sets.

> Is it the case that: $\sf HRC \models |\omega|=|\mathcal P(\omega)| $?

> Does that hold for any infinite set $x$ in $\sf HRC$?

The idea is that the usual proof of Cantor's theorem is blocked here, since the diagonal appears as an element at $>1$ higher constructible stage, and so it is not rank-concordant, and so doesn't exist in $\sf HRC$. On the other hand $L$ does prove $|L_\alpha| = \alpha$ for every infinite cardinal $\alpha$, and so $L$ proves that the set of all rank-concordant subsets of an infinite constructible set is equal in cardinality to that set. But is it the case that we can prove the existence of a hereditarily rank-concordant bijection between $\omega$ and $\mathcal P(\omega)$? And does that apply to every infinite set in $\sf HRC$ ?

**Note:** by $|x|=|y|$ it means there exists a bijection between $x$ and $y$, and a bijection is defined here as a set of Kuratowski ordered pairs satisfying the usual qualifications of bijections.

Comment: Your model HRC is not a model of a reasonable set theory. Separation will fail, even at very low levels of complexity, and many other things will go wrong. To see this, notice that all ordinals are in HRC, and one can get copies of constructible sets in HRC by inserting big dummy ordinals into them to push up the rank, so that their definability level matches their subset level. So these copies will be in HRC, but the uncopied transcriptions of them will not be. So HRC will violate separation. It seems to me that HRC will not even be able to perform set intersections.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, it is reasonable as long as we maintain predactivity confines, and I mean predicativity as related to type theory and stratified theories. So, Separation and Intersections only work within those confines. However, what I wanted to know is if $|\omega|=|\mathcal P(\omega)|$ is provable, disprovable, or undecidable in the theory of $\sf HRC$. we know that $\sf ZF+[V=L]$ proves the existence of bijections between the infinite stages $L_\alpha$'s and their ordinal indices; are these bijections hereditarily concordant?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I think using the dummy ordinals you've mentioned may provide an answer to the second question, since using a suitable ordinal as dummy would recover Cantor's diagonal argument and so prove Cantor's theorem for that set. But, still the first question is unanswered.

Comment: Because HRC does not satisfy a reasonable set theory, you have to say exactly what you mean by $|\omega|=|P(\omega)|$. For example, you might mean there is a function from $\omega$ to $P(\omega)$, but what is a function? This depends on how you define ordered pairs, and not all the definitions will be equivalent, because the Kurotowski pair definition will push up ranks a little, but flat pairing functions will not. In a reasonable theory, the question will not depend on this kind of thing, but because HRC is set-theoretically ignorant, it will. This is why the question is not interesting.

Comment: In HRC, the dummy ordinal member will show that there is a definable bijection of $\omega$ with $P(\omega)$, but you cannot turn this easily into a set that is a function, and as I said it will depend on what you mean by ordered pairs.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, I see what you mean, I've edited the question and written the definition of equal cardinality. It is the usual one using the Kuratowski ordered pairs.